# Getting Error:No directive found with exportAs 'ngModel'. Using Template Form in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-template

I have the following html in my-pin.component.html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6" id='pinInput'>
            <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"  #f>
                <label for="pin">Enter Pin</label>
                <input type="number" name="userPin" id="userPin" required ngModel #myPin="ngModel">
                <span class="help-block" *ngIf="!myPin.valid && myPinPin.touched">Please enter your pin</span>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!f.valid">Submit</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
```

As well as the pin.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { PinRoutingModule } from './pin-routing.module';
import { MyPinComponent } from './my-pin/my-pin.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
declarations: [
MyPinComponent
],
imports: [
CommonModule,
PinRoutingModule,
FormsModule
]
})
export class PinModule { }
```

The structure of files are pin(contains app.files)->my-pin(new module containing module files and component files.

I am getting the known No directive found with exportAs 'ngModel'. error when trying to compile this. I am trying to make sure user enters something in number textbox (a pin) and to show an error if the data is not entered.

Answer (score 1):

Found this in your code `myPinPin.touched`, I hope it's just a typo if not please change it to `myPin.touched`.

```
 <input type="number" name="userPin" id="userPin" required ngModel #myPin="ngModel">
                <span class="help-block" *ngIf="!myPin.valid && myPin.touched">Please enter your pin</span>
```

Also try to set the ***ngModel*** since your are using template driven forms. Something like below after declaring it in component (template)

```
[(ngModel)]="userPin"
```

Please read more here about [template driven form error handling](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation). Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

remove that #myPin="ngModel" and try again